# SharePoint Client Context: Load Query RoleAssignment returned "Not well formatted JSON Stream"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, asp.net

We are experiencing this issue that when we are querying data from Role Assignment of a SharePoint Site it throws an exception "Not Well Formatted JSON Stream". In this line `i => i.RoleAssignments.Include(ra => ra.PrincipalId, ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings, ra => ra.Member))`, `ra.RoleDefinitionsBindings` and `ra.Member` throws the exception. Please advise on what can we do and what is causing this exception.

Comment: Hi @user92521, Is there any updates ? If the reply is helpful to this question, you could accept as answer so that it could help others in the forum :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to query role assignments in CSOM like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> GetSitePermissionDetails(ClientContext clientContext)
        {
            IEnumerable roles = clientContext.LoadQuery(clientContext.Web.RoleAssignments.Include(roleAsg => roleAsg.PrincipalId,roleAsg=>roleAsg.Member,
                                                                              roleAsg => roleAsg.RoleDefinitionBindings.Include(roleDef => roleDef.Name)));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Dictionary<string, string> permisionDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (RoleAssignment ra in roles)
            {
                var rdc = ra.RoleDefinitionBindings;
                string permission = string.Empty;
                foreach (var rdbc in rdc)
                {
                    permission += rdbc.Name.ToString() + ", ";
                }
                permisionDetails.Add(ra.Member.Title, permission);
            }
            return permisionDetails;
        }
```

Call:

```
    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev");
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic = GetSitePermissionDetails(ctx);
```

Reference:

[Get SharePoint Permissions Programmatically Using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-sharepoint-permissions-programmatically-using-csom/)